# how to get the rect of an image to crop it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, cgrect

I am building a app where you can crop multiple images. I am using this code directly from apple:

```
 func cropImage(_ inputImage: UIImage, toRect cropRect: CGRect, viewWidth: CGFloat, viewHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage? 
{    
let imageViewScale = max(inputImage.size.width / viewWidth,
                             inputImage.size.height / viewHeight)

    // Scale cropRect to handle images larger than shown-on-screen size
    let cropZone = CGRect(x:cropRect.origin.x * imageViewScale,
                          y:cropRect.origin.y * imageViewScale,
                          width:cropRect.size.width * imageViewScale,
                          height:cropRect.size.height * imageViewScale)

    // Perform cropping in Core Graphics
    guard let cutImageRef: CGImage = inputImage.cgImage?.cropping(to:cropZone)
    else {
        return nil
    }

    // Return image to UIImage
    let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef)
    return croppedImage
}
```

to crop the image I need a cropRect. I found also a solution in the Internet that I implemented in my code:

```
func realImageRect() -> CGRect {
    let imageViewSize = self.frame.size
    let imgSize = self.image?.size

    guard let imageSize = imgSize else {
        return CGRect.zero
    }

    let scaleWidth = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width
    let scaleHeight = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height
    let aspect = fmin(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)

    var imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width * aspect, height: imageSize.height * aspect)


    // Center image
    imageRect.origin.x = (imageViewSize.width - imageRect.size.width) / 2
    imageRect.origin.y = (imageViewSize.height - imageRect.size.height) / 2

    // Add imageView offset
    imageRect.origin.x += self.frame.origin.x
    imageRect.origin.y += self.frame.origin.y

    return imageRect
}
```

As I already said, the app can crop multiple images. The images are stored in a array. I also have a crop view, which you can drag around the image with a pan gesture

```
   for i in 0..<imageContentView.count {
        let cropRect = CGRect(x: croppedViewArray[i].frame.origin.x - imageContentView[i].realImageRect().origin.x, y: croppedViewArray[i].frame.origin.y - imageContentView[i].realImageRect().origin.y, width: croppedViewArray[i].frame.width, height: croppedViewArray[i].frame.height)

        print("cropRect", cropRect)
        let croppedImage = ImageCrophandler.sharedInstance.cropImage(imageContentView[i].image!, toRect: cropRect, viewWidth: imageContentView[i].frame.width, viewHeight: imageContentView[i].frame.height)


        print("cheight", croppedImage!.size.height,"cwidth", croppedImage!.size.width)
        arrayOfCropedImages.append(croppedImage!)

    }
```

The problem what I have is, that every cropped image has a different height and widths, but the images should be all the same size.
I figured out that the size gets calculated on which position the crop view is located.

Comment: checkout cocoapod `CropViewController`, gives you the native crop feel and rotate and undo

Comment: I want to do it on my own

Comment: Do you want to crop center part of each image?

Comment: Yes this is correct